# How to receive return parameters of a telegram bot method (API)

Tags: java, jsp, telegram, telegram-bot

I have a local web page by [JSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Pages), and I can sendMessage or sendPhoto to a telegram user by the telegram robot [API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface) through this page. But after submitting this request from my page, the URL redirects to another page that return values of the telegram Bot API method shown there. I want to get these parameters and return values on my local page, and I don't want to go to that URL.

This is for example:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<html>
    <head></head>

    <body>
        <form action="https://api.telegram.org/bot<token>/sendMessage" method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="chat_id" id="chat_id"value="myChatId">
            <input type="text" name="text" id="text" value="hello">
            <input type="submit" value="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I click submit this page appears:

https://api.telegram.org/bot<Token>/sendMessage and results of the request is shown to me and hello is send to the user by the Id of myChatId. So, I want this page does not show, and I will be on my current local page, but I can receive and see results and return parameters of sending the message by this method on my local page.

Comment: What you are doing is wrong. You need to make server side requests to Telegram API not client side requests.

Comment: you mean that I should not send form and I should send a request by java(for example or php)? So,how can I get the result and parameters sent by telegram api like user_id to store in DB?@ariaby

Comment: Yes, Any programming language but from server side. then you just make a request and get back the result.Like this in PHP:

```php

$response=$this->telegram->sendMessage($chatId,$message);

```

Comment: another question... Can I import some contacts for my robot? I mean can robots have contact list? if yes how can we import contacts to this list? Is there any way?@ariaby

Comment: No bots don't have contact list but you can receive contact files from your users.
https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#contact

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an [ajax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) request from your local page to telegram api url with post method and block page reload:

[**Run in jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/sadeghpm/zcye6fs5/6/)

```js
$('form').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' + $('#token').val() + '/sendMessage',
    method: 'POST',
    data: {
      chat_id: $('#chat_id').val(),
      text: $('#text').val()
    },
    success: function() {
      alert('your message has been sent!');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <input type="text" name='token' id="token" placeholder="your bot token">
  <input type="text" name="chat_id" id="chat_id" value="myChatId">
  <input type="text" name="text" id="text" value="hello">
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```